# iOS GameCenter authorization window block Chartboost

Tags: ios, game-center, chartboost

I call Chartboost interstitial at `applicationDidBecomeActive`. My game use s Game Center and sometimes GC authorization window pops up under `Chartboost` interstitial, blocking `Chartboost` window. Only solution is switch to `GameCenter` and login there. Is it possible to check what authorization window was shown?

Comment: Are you using their latest SDK? Either SDK 3.2 or 3.2.1? According to their changelog in SDK 3.2: -Handles showing an interstitial at the same time as the Game Center login prompt I recommend emailing support@chartboost.com as they may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking ads when Game Center login is on screen might be an option! Code works only on iOS6 btw

```
@interface ChartboostBridge : NSObject<ChartboostDelegate>
@end

@implementation ChartboostBridge 

- (BOOL)shouldDisplayInterstitial:(NSString *)location{

    NSLog(@"CB shouldDisplayInterstitial for %@",location);

    if ([location isEqualToString:@"game_launch"]) {

        if( [[GameCenterIos shared ] hasLogInView] ){

            return NO;
        }

    }

    return YES;
}

@end


@implementation GameCenterIos

- (BOOL)hasLogInView{

    return  isViewOnScreen;
}

- (void)login
{
    GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
        isViewOnScreen=NO;
        return;
    }

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler =
        ^(UIViewController *viewController,
    NSError *error) {


        if (localPlayer.authenticated) {
            isAuthenticated = YES;
            isViewOnScreen=NO;
        } else if(viewController) {
            NSLog(@"Game Center shows login ....");
            isViewOnScreen=YES;
            [self presentViewController:viewController];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Game Center error or canceled login ....");
            //User canceled Login view
            isAuthenticated = NO;
            isViewOnScreen=NO;
        }
    };
}

#pragma mark UIViewController stuff

-(UIViewController*) getRootViewController {
    return [UIApplication 
        sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
}

-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController*)vc {
    UIViewController* rootVC = [self getRootViewController];
    [rootVC presentViewController:vc animated:YES 
        completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. Used same way, but add check for iOS <6.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is and old question but I just had the same problem and found a workaround.

Change the modalPresentationStyle of the gamecenter loggin view (returned by the ios 6 authentication handler) to **UIModalPresentationFullScreen**.

On iphone the screen doesn't lock when gamecenter loggin and chartboost interstitial appear. Only on Ipad happens. And whats the difference? that in ipad the loggin is not fullscreen. So I tested changing it to fullscreen and now it works without locking =)